# Bad Display Name when running Python script on boot with Touch Screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspbian, touchscreen

Attempting to run a Python script on boot on Raspberry Pi 3B+ 1GB RAM, Raspbian, with a [SunFounder 10" Touch Screen](https://www.sunfounder.com/10-1-touch-screen-display-1501.html),  - .log file returns "Bad display name'

Python script is 100% functional when run via Terminal / executable script / Thonny etc. Attempted to run at boot first via rc.local - created a service, enabled service, daemon-reload... etc. Did not work.
Tried to run as crontab, same result - .log output from crontab shows "Bad display name". Thought it was lack of Display Environment imported and declared within the Python script, so I added that - but on boot returns the same result.

This is the Python Script I'm using

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import time
import subprocess
from pynput import keyboard
from Xlib.display import Display

#GPIO Readout
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#GPIO Header Setup
header = 2
GPIO.setup(header, GPIO.IN)

#Omxplayer Commands
Loop = 'omxplayer -b --loop --no-osd -o hdmi /home/pi/Videos/PlanetEarth.mp4 > /dev/null'
Donation = 'omxplayer -b --no-osd -o hdmi /home/pi/Videos/Cartoon.mp4 > /dev/null'
KillPlayer = 'pkill omxplayer.bin'
KillForm = 'pkill chromium'

#Set Display Environment
new_env = dict(os.environ)
new_env['DISPLAY'] = ':0.0'

#Form Handling Required Below
#If Donation is successful, Stop Looping Video, Open Form in Chromium, Wait 60 seconds, Close Chromium, Restart Loop
def PullDownSuccess():
    subprocess.Popen(KillPlayer, env=new_env, shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    webbrowser.open('<url>')
    time.sleep(60)
    subprocess.Popen(KillForm, env=new_env, shell=True)
    time.sleep(2)
    subprocess.Popen(Loop, env=new_env, shell=True)

#Inception
subprocess.Popen(Loop, env=new_env, shell=True)

#Terminate Loop with Escape Key or Manually Initiate Donation Success
def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.ctrl:
        PullDownSuccess()
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        subprocess.Popen(KillPlayer, shell=True)

#Keyboard Listener Module
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

#Donation Successful Do:
while True:
    header_state = GPIO.input(header)
    if header_state == GPIO.HIGH:
        PullDownSuccess()
```

I am currently attempting to run this script on Boot via crontab with this line:

```
@reboot (/bin/sleep 10; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>.py > /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

The error log file for crontab returns the following:

```
    raise error.DisplayNameError(display)
Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
```

This error only exists when attempting to run script on boot up. Is the Display overriding the boot display permissions on Boot Up? What is keeping the script from running on the Display on boot up, but not when remotely executed? Thank you for your consideration.

---

**Update: Still no solution.** Display environment returns ":0.0' ... so far I have tried to remove

```
> /dev/null from #Omxplayer Commands
```

Replacing crontab startup line to:

```
DISPLAY=":0" /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>.py
```

and

```
DISPLAY=":0.0" /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>.py
```

And any possible combination of these.

Confirmed the script is not waiting for any background processes as I have added delay (time.sleep) up to 30 seconds, as well as returning IP addresses, etc.

Returns either Bad Display Name still OR "Can't connect to display ":0": b'Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key"

Still looking for a solution if anyone has one.

**EDIT:**
Fixed using /LXDE-pi/autostart. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are unforeseen ramifications for using this method, I will update this thread accordingly. I fixed this issue just by adding two lines to the autostart file which resides in /etc/sdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart.

```
sudo nano /etc/xgd/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add these two lines, do not modify the existing code.

```
sleep 5
@/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>.py
```

My autostart file looks like this:

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
point-rpi
sleep 5
@usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>/py
```

Ctrl + O to write file

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add DISPLAY environment variable before calling your script:

```
DISPLAY=":0" /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. ```DISPLAY=":0" /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>.py```
This returns: "Can't connect to display ":0": b'Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key'"

Comment: Well, I can't help you with that for now as I [created an issue](https://github.com/ipaleka/arrangeit/issues/31) targeting the same error for my project recently.

Comment: Haha... well, I'll let you know what I find if I find a solution!

Comment: I am using a monitor attached via VGA cable and `DISPLAY=":1"` worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`DISPLAY="/dev/null" /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Custom_Scripts/<script>.py`

Have you tried a longer sleep?

Comment: Tried longer sleep, as well as declaring DISPLAY="/dev/null" - Same Bad Display Name result.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to get your ip adress during your startup script with (for example) :

```
  import socket
  def get_ip_address():
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
        return s.getsockname()[0]
```

you will get an errror like:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
>       return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
>     error: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

This is because at reboot network is not necessarily available. In order to make it available 
see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45769/how-to-wait-for-networking-on-login-after-reboot :

> sudo raspi-config

then select option 3 Boot Options
then select option 4 Wait for network at boot

Once you have done that networking should not be an issue at reboot.

You get also check for other ways to enforce network setup before running your script take a look at :
https://askubuntu.com/questions/3299/how-to-run-cron-job-when-network-is-up

Comment: Thanks for your input. Making sure the boot option is set to wait for network is good practice. I have changed my boot options to reflect your suggestion. However, it does not address the display issue. Do you have any input on the Bad Display Name that exists on boot up?

Comment: Did you try including the `get_ip_address()` in your python script just to see if you get the correct IP and that your network is up ?

Comment: To humor you - print (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())) returns my correct IP - Nothing is wrong with my network connection. Network is up and 100% prior to all processes of my script running successfully. Nothing in the script is done via network. Everything is run local. Is there a reason for diverting from my original question and topic?

Comment: Because when I tried to reproduce your issue get_ip_address() gave me the error above and prior to that I had a Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name "". Since DISPLAY is used by X11 server to deport DISPLAY I thought it was a network issue. I forced network at boot and no longer observed any issue with DISPLAY after that. So I thought it was the key to solving your issue. Bad guess it seems. Are you able to have a more detail stack trace error by the way, it would help ?

Comment: I understand now. I appreciate you for being so thorough. I'll attempt some more methods and get a more detailed stack trace error, and get back to you soon. Continual Thanks.