# Python script fails in cronjob

Tags: python, cron

Not sure why crontab is not able to run the following code as it encounters error with PyMouse. Running it manually has no problems at all.

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
import csv

m = PyMouse()
file = open('/fullpath/track.csv','rb+',newline='')

with file:
    header =['x','y']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file,fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'x':m.position()[0],'y':m.position()[1]})
```

From `cat /var/spool/mail/doug` I see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/doug/Desktop/track/mouse.py", line 4, in <module>
    m = PyMouse()
  File "/home/doug/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymouse/x11.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.display = Display(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 89, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 71, in __init__
    protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 85, in __init__
    name, protocol, host, displayno, screenno = connect.get_display(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 73, in get_display
    return mod.get_display(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 61, in get_display
    raise error.DisplayNameError(display)
Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
```

The closest solution I've come to is [Bad Display Name when running Python script on boot with Touch Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997480/bad-display-name-when-running-python-script-on-boot-with-touch-screen) but it doesn't apply to me.

Below is my cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * * DISPLAY=":0" python3 /home/doug/Desktop/track/mouse.py --user
```

Comment: You can't use `PyMouse` in a cron job, it doesn't have a console connected to it.

Comment: Is there a way that I can run a program that uses pymouse in the background?

Comment: Why do you think that other answer doesn't apply to you?

Comment: Try putting `DISPLAY=":0"` at the beginning of the command in the crontab.

Comment: If you do that, you will have to run the cron job as the logged on user.  Do you have it in the roon crontab now?

Comment: ```DISPLAY=":0"``` didn't make a difference for me unfortunately. I'll paste my cronjob in my post. I'll edit it